# Книга по ассемблеру под Windows для начинающего

Tags: ассемблер, книги

Здравствуйте , посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошую книгу по ассемблеру . 
Пробовал начинать читать Пирогова и другие, но для меня это пока что сложновато , хотелось бы книгу чтобы подробно было все описано , практически с нуля. А то начинаешь читать , и сразу идут примеры , то есть надо какие-то базовые знания ассемблера . Еще желательно чтобы книга была 2000+ года выпуска(чтобы имела описание команд и архитектур более новых процессоров). И еще хотелось бы чтобы сразу все операции были под Windows , так как ДОС сейчас уже не актуален . 
Спасибо заранее

Comment: дос не актуален? ну да. про реальный режим работы современных 8086-like процессоров на старте слыхали?..

Answer (score 2):

@Alexandr Crospov

> Еще желательно чтобы книга была 2000+ года выпуска(чтобы имела описание команд и архитектур более новых процессоров).

Неактуально. Вы сначала с базовым набором инструкций архитектуры x86 разберитесь, а затем уже учите расширения MMX, 3DNow, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, x64 и пр.

> И еще хотелось бы чтобы сразу все операции были под Windows , так как ДОС сейчас уже не актуален

Операции под ДОС и Виндовс абсолютно идентичны. Единственное, что используются разные API. Для ДОСа придется использовать прерывания(INT xx) для того, чтобы открывать/закрывать файлы, рисовать на экран и пр. Под виндой же - использовать ф-ции стандартных библиотек виндовс.

По книгам:

1. Виктор Юров: Assembler. Учебник для вузов
2. Сергей Зубков: Assembler для DOS, Windows и UNIX
3. Юрий Магда: Ассемблер для процессоров Intel Pentium

Это то что вспоминается сразу. А вообще на том же ozon.ru куча литературы по ассемблеру. Например, [такая книга](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=1&pvalue=%DF%E7%FB%EA+%E0%F1%F1%E5%EC%E1%EB%E5%F0%E0+%E4%EB%FF+%EF%F0%EE%F6%E5%F1%F1%EE%F0%EE%E2+Intel+%2B+CD-ROM&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) вроде выглядит адекватно.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором. Ассемблер (как и любой другой язык программирования) - это, в первую очередь, способ мышления. Например, одна из книг по языку Форт так и называется "Способ мышления - Форт". Рекомендую сделать так: скачать книгу Журдена "Справочник программиста на персональном компьютере фирмы IBM" (ничего понятнее и интереснее не видел на эту тему) и осваивать ее в эмуляторе ДОСа. Есть даже люди, которые до сих пор программируют на ассемблере для компьютера ZX Spectrum. Очень, знаете ли, дисциплинирует. А конкретные мнемонические команды или номера прерываний мало что меняют. В Линуксе одно, в Виндоуз другое. Это как разница между Си и Паскалем. По большому счету всего лишь синтаксис. Очередной язык в рамках знакомой парадигмы изучается очень быстро.

Comment: Ох уж мне эти сказочки. Ох уж мне эти сказочники...

А разница между Си и паскалем -- далеко не только синтаксис. Там и идеология разная. Только где сейчас найдёшь этот паскаль-то...  (delphi и т.п. не предлагать -- сильно другой язык)

Comment: @deivan у ассемблера ниша вообще маленькая. Сравнима с нишей для форта, но зато превышает нишу программирования на postscript (есть фаны)