# Изучение ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Привет. У меня на экране книга Калашникова по Ассемблеру. Думаю, читать её или нет. Один человек мне сказал, что она уже устарела и этот ассемблер никто не использует. Это правда?

**Вопрос 1:**  Тогда какой используют?

**Вопрос 2:**  Посоветуйте современную литературу по ассемблеру ну или ту, которую вы считаете нужной для новичка.

Большое спасибо

Comment: А что, есть _ещё какой-то_ ассемблер? о_О

Comment: ASM по сути своей не имеет версии или возраста. Разница лишь только в конкретной архитектуре и количестве поддерживаемых директив, да и то основы - практически везде повторяются. Как по мне, легче всего ASM понимался на старых процессорах (вплоть до 8088, где набор команд на пальцах посчитать) и\или как результат асм-вставок в каком-нибудь древнем C++.

Comment: Вот, рекомендую книгу - вытащил книжку с пыльной полки специально для вас :) Старая и это совсем не минус. Зубков С. В. Assembler для DOS, Windows и UNIX. Надеюсь помог. 

Такая обложка http://s010.radikal.ru/i314/1609/5c/158285f28d13.jpg (простите за ссылку на радикале)

Comment: @GRUNGER большое спасибо, товарищ. Буду осваивать!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книга по ассемблеру под Windows для начинающего](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275287/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-windows-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Все что нельзя написать на ассемблере, можно только спаять

Ассемблер — это практически самый древний язык программирования. До него было лишь программирование в машинных кодах. Будем считать, что если вы соберетесь писать какую-нибудь серьезную программу на ASM, я думаю вы забросите это дело в самом начале. Сейчас написание программы на языке низкого уровня это не лучшее дело, всякий софт для микроконтроллеров уже давно пишут на C.

Помню раньше, когда появились языки высокого уровня, народ еще вставлял куски ассемблерного кода, и ты вот сидишь и думаешь что перепиливание критических участков кода может принести PROFIT, а может и не принести.

Сейчас написание чего-то серьезного и большого на ассемблере это просто невыгодно по времени и затрачиваемым ресурсам, ведь все это можно написать быстрее и кросс платформенее.

Будем считать, что вопрос о том, что писать в коммерческих целях на ассемблере это уже не актуально, но вот в учебных целях - писать нужно и обязательно пишите и изучайте!

**Ведь благодаря тому, что вы напишите парочку программ на языке низкого уровня вы узнаете много нового.**

Даже если вы пишете программу на языке высокого уровня, знание ассемблера поможет понять, как будет выполнятся программа, как хранятся переменные, как вызываются функции. А это позволит избежать многих очень неприятных ошибок. Есть такие люди, которые знают программирование только на уровне языка. То есть знают что надо написать, чтобы получить какой-то результат. А как оно работает, для них остается тайной, покрытой мраком. Человек, владеющий ассемблером, будет лучше программировать и на других языках.

Знание ассемблера позволяет расковырять любую программу дизассемблером и изучить механизм её работы! Только представьте — можно залезть внутрь любой программы и посмотреть как она работает. Иногда бывает, что попадается интересная программа и не понятно, что там внутри, как она написана. Зная ассемблер, можно заглянуть внутрь любой программы и удовлетворить свое любопытство, даже не имея исходников.

Ассемблер очень может помочь при отладке. Иногда случаются ошибки и в компиляторах — очень злая тема. Вроде бы корректно написанный код выполняется вовсе не так, как предполагалось. Чтобы обнаружить такую ошибку надо посмотреть, во что скомпилился код, а разобраться в этом без ассемблера невозможно.

По книгам, можете брать абсолютно любую которая Вам понравиться и читать, тут ограничений никаких, почти во всех книгах расписаны устройства регистров, функции и т.д. Я в учебном курсе писал на FASM, достаточно удобный компилятор ассемблера.

**P.S AX BX CX DX - I like to mov it mov it**